# Mapping ORACLE's NUMBER Type with Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, mapping

I have a table in a ORACLE 10g database with a column "`kzCode NUMBER(1)`".

If I try to map this with Hibernate annotations in JBOSS Server WebApp like this:

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private Integer kzCode;
```

I got an error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type: kzCode, expected: integer
```

I also tried

```
@Column(nullable=false) private BigInteger kzCode;
```

error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type: kzCode, expected:numeric(19,2)
```

I don't really know, what Java type to take.

Answer (score 1):

ok, got it!

I had a wrong dialect property in persistence.xml file.
Now all works fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private Boolean kzCode;
```

or if you really want it to be a number, change the Oracle type to NUMBER(36, 0) and use long or Long in your Java.